# prevent page reloading second view in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I am new to Jquery mobile, In my Index.html page when I click on search button list will generate dynamically using ajax call, when I click on list It will go to display page and display all the values. Problem is when I come back from display page to search and click on list again ajax call happen two times(means Page is reloading two times).
I am using $(document).on('pageinit', function() {});

Please fine the code below:

index.html

```
<input type="button" id='sear' value="Search">  
 <div id="output" data-dom-cache="true">
  <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="display">
  </ul>
 </div>
```

search.js

```
 $.post("mobileser", {data},function(res) {
  $('#output ul').append("<li> <a href=./mobile/pages/details.html data-ajax='false'>"+'Incident No: '+v+' </li>'+'</a>');
  $('#display').listview('refresh');
```

details.html

```
<input type="text" id="Module"  name="Module" placeholder="AutoComplete" data-mini="true"  >
<input type='hidden' value='' name="hmoduleId" id="hmoduleId" class="autoCompleteCheck" />
```

viewdetails.js

```
$(document).on(pageinit, function() {
 $.post("url", {data}, function(res) {
  $(Module).val(value);
 },)
})
```

Please help me...

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: This is a known problem (and it is not a bug). Show us your code so we can show you how to fix it. Also take a look at my other article: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/1848600, search for a chapter: Prevent multiple event binding/triggering

Comment: hi, you got the clarity or do u want to post all the code

Comment: can u plz update on this

Answer (score 0):

Use e.preventDefault() to Prevent Postback based on you condition